# Jmeter - Unable to execute HTTP request successfully after first instance

Tags: jmeter

My script has multiple http request of creating, authorising a record and then to delete that record.
I am running this for 2 users, it works fine for the 1st user but for the next instance, it sends the delete request properly but it doesn't reflect on the app. That means the record is not deleted. All the runtime parameters are passed correctly as the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just reusing your script as is after recording then it explains your problem.

You need after recording to variabilize and make correlation for all ID that are related to your recording.

See this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have modified the script after recording and sending parameters and session details but it doesn't help